# Efficient way to dedupe Hive table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I'm working with a data pipeline similar to Airflow and want to have a daily task that checks if a new partition has landed in a table and then create a new table with all duplicate records removed.

The dataset is quite large, so I'm struggling to think of an efficient HiveQL query to dedupe it with. Simply using a group by over all the columns is certainly too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select col1, col2, col3, . . .,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, . . . 
                                order by col1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I'm not sure how much faster than a `group by` this will be, but it is worth a try.